# Changing label text of second ViewController upon clicking button in first ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and to iOS Development. I currently have 2 `ViewControllers`, a `button` in the first and a `label` in the second one. I've connected the first `button` to the second `ViewController` and the transition works.

Now, when I try changing the label's text I get the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value

.

Here you find my prepare function in the first `ViewController`:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            vc.secondResultLabel.text = "Testing"
         }
    }
```

Can it be that the label in the second `ViewController` is somehow protected ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: This looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887587/error-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-while-pass-data-to-the-new/39887622#39887622

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the `String` to the `SecondViewController` instead of directing setting it, as the `UILabel` has not been created yet.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        vc.secondResultLabelText = "Testing"
    }
}
```

And in your `SecondViewController` `viewDidLoad` method set the `UILabel` to be the string

```
var secondResultLabelText : String!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    secondResultLabelText.text = secondResultLabelText
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add a string variable in the second view controller

```
var labelText: String!
```

in second view controller also (in viewDidLoad)

```
self.secondResultLabel.text = self.labelText
```

then first view controller prepare for segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        vc.labelText = "Testing"
     }
}
```

this is because second view controller's UILabel Outlet is not being initialized yet in prepare for segue

Rikh's answer is the same, both his answer and mine are the same

Answer (score 2):

Welcome aboard :)

Your problem is that your `SecondViewController`, and more specifically `vc.secondResultLabelText` is not initiated when you call `prepare`, so `secondResultLabel` is actually nil at that time.

You need to add a variable to your `SecondViewController` like so:

```
var labelText: String = ""
```

And then set that value instead:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        vc.labelText = "Testing"
     }
}
```

In `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` on your `SecondViewController` you can then use that value for your `secondResultLabelText` which is now ready, connected, and won't crash

```
secondResultLabelText.text = labelText
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First take a global variable in SecondViewController... eg I took "secondViewControllerVariable". Then get the text you want to display in your SecondViewController.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 

    {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" 
            {
                let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
                vc.secondViewControllerVariable = "Your string you get in FirstViewController"
            }
    }
```

And then  in your SecondViewController, in viewDidLoad method set the UILabel to be the string

```
   var secondViewControllerVariable : String! // You have to declare this first in your SecondViewController Globally 

   override func viewDidLoad() 
     {
          vc.secondResultLabelText.text = secondViewControllerVariable
     }
```

That's it.  Happy Coding.