# How to change the label of a different view controller when selecting data from a tableviewcontrollerin Swift 3 / xCode 8?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a view controller which is used as a table view. From the table view I wish to select an item from the rows available and once selected I wish for that chosen thing to be the name of a label in a second view controller.

So 
tableViewController - select an item from the list in the table

secondViewcontroller - label name is what is selected in the tableViewController

I have looked around and there is talk of using NSNotification but I can't seem to get it to work, in addition to using prepareForSegue.
My relevant code for the tableViewContrller is this:

```
//MARK Table View
    //number of sections the table will have
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //number of rows each section of the table will have
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return peripheralArray.count
    }

    //the way the data will be displayed in each row for the sections
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let BluetoothNaming = peripheralArray[indexPath.row].peripheral.name
        cell.textLabel?.text = BluetoothNaming

        return cell
    }

    //what happens when we select an item from the bluetooth list
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        stopScanning()
        peripheral = peripheralArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].peripheral
        print ("connecting to peripheral called \(peripheral)")

        //store the name of the connected peripeheral
        let connectedPeripheral = peripheral
        manager?.connect(connectedPeripheral!, options: nil)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueBackwards", sender: nil)
    }
```

My secondViewController does not have much on its just the label:

```
import UIKit

class HomepageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var ConnectionLabel: UILabel!

    func changeBlueoothLabel() {
        self.ConnectionLabel.text = "aaaa"
    }
}
```

What do I need to do so that when I select a row in the table that the label in the secondViewController changes its label to reflect it.

Furthermore, if I wanted to change it so that I have another label on the secondViewController and I wanted to change it from disconnected to connected, would there be much more work involved?

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765272/changing-label-text-of-second-viewcontroller-upon-clicking-button-in-first-viewc/40765351)

Comment: It is somewhat similar but not the same..although I am sure someone with more experience could work of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pass data add a string variable in the HomepageViewController and implement prepareForSegue method to pass selected name from tableViewController to HomepageViewController

**in HomepageViewController**

```
var selectedName: String?
```

**in tableViewController:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showHomePage" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let peripheral = peripheralArray[indexPath.row].peripheral.name
            let homeController = segue.destination as! HomepageViewController
             homeController.selectedName = peripheral
        }
    }
```

**in HomepageViewController**

```
import UIKit

class HomepageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var ConnectionLabel: UILabel!
    var selectedName: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Used the text from the First View Controller to set the label
        if let name = selectedName {
           ConnectionLabel.text = name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works in the sense that it does not crash, however the text itself does not change.
Any thoughts on what may be needed to change?

Comment: I did some checking on it too, the if statement stops when it get to this bit
'if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow'

Comment: remove tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) comment in didSelect method and try

Comment: perfect, thank you very much Suhit :) :)
I would upvote but I don't have enough points to do so but I have marked yours as the correct answer